# How do I iterate over a DataFrame when apply won't work without a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, chaining

I am trying to find the best way to apply my function to each individual row of a pandas DataFrame without using `iterrows()` or `itertuples()`. Note that I am pretty sure `apply()` will not work in this case.

Here the first 5 rows of the DataFrame that I'm working with:

```
In [2470]: home_df.head()
Out[2470]: 
   GameId  GameId_real       team  FTHG  FTAG  homeElo  awayElo  homeGame  
0       0           -1   Charlton   1.0   2.0   1500.0   1500.0         1   
1       1           -1      Derby   2.0   1.0   1500.0   1500.0         1   
2       2           -1      Leeds   2.0   0.0   1500.0   1500.0         1   
3       3           -1  Leicester   0.0   5.0   1500.0   1500.0         1   
4       4           -1  Liverpool   2.0   1.0   1500.0   1500.0         1
```

Here is my function and the code that I am currently using:

```
def wt_goals_elo(df, game_id_row, team_row):
    wt_goals = (df[(df.GameId < game_id_row) & (df.team == team_row)]
                  .pipe(lambda df: 
                        (df.awayElo * df.FTHG).sum() / df.awayElo.sum()))
    return wt_goals

game_id_idx = home_df.columns.get_loc('GameId')
team_idx = home_df.columns.get_loc('team')

wt_goals = [wt_goals_elo(home_df, row[game_id_idx + 1], row[team_idx + 1]) for row in home_df.itertuples()]
```

FTHG = Full time home goals.
I am basically trying to find the weighted average of full time home goals, weighted by away elo for previous games. I can do this using a for loop but am unable to do it using apply, as I need to refer to the original DataFrame to filter by GameId and team.
Any ideas?
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe need:

```
def wt_goals_elo(game_id_row, team_row):
    print (game_id_row)
    wt_goals = (home_df[(home_df.GameId.shift() < game_id_row) & 
               (home_df.team.shift() == team_row)]
                  .pipe(lambda df: 
                        (df.awayElo * df.FTHG).sum() / df.awayElo.sum()))
    return wt_goals


home_df['w'] = home_df.apply(lambda x: wt_goals_elo(x['GameId'], x['team']), axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried this method before asking the question, but I believe because the `apply` method doesn't loop over the rows, providing it the parameters x['GameId'] and x['team'] doesn't actually give it what we are intending. I get a TypeError:`TypeError: ("wt_goals_elo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'team_row'", 'occurred at index 0')` and if I put in the dataframe as an argument I get `AttributeError: ("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'awayElo'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: @JamesWard - Sorry, I was no clear. apply is under the hood loop.

Comment: When I run your edited code I get:
`AttributeError: ("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'team'", 'occurred at index 0')`. As I said, I'm quite sure apply won't work by itself in this specific case. Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: @JamesWard - Just see all comment. Function was changed a bit - there is changed first row from `wt_goals = (df[(df.GameId < game_id_row) & (df.team == team_row)]` to `(home_df[(home_df.GameId.shift() < game_id_row) & (home_df.team.shift() == team_row)]`

Comment: @JamesWard - Last row was a bit changed, it is assigned to new column. Is paramterr `axis=1` correct in `apply` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error: `AttributeError: ("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'awayElo'", 'occurred at index 0')`. Yes `axis=1`. I am literally copying and pasting your code.

Comment: Ok, I check it by `home_df = pd.DataFrame({'GameId': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'GameId_real': [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 'team': ['Charlton', 'Derby', 'Leeds', 'Leicester', 'Liverpool'], 'FTHG': [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0], 'FTAG': [2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0], 'homeElo': [1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0], 'awayElo': [1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0], 'homeGame': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})` and it working (in sample return all NaNs, but it is expected, because no duplicates `team` values)